# В Викисловаре или на Викисловаре?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

С одной стороны, имеется в виду словарь. С другой стороны, это как-никак сайт. Какой вариант предпочтителен?

Comment: Предлог "на" более  уместен в том случае, если есть слово сайт. Напр.: На сайте Викисловаря.

Comment: Или в случае предлога "на" можно поставить название сайта в кавычки - это покажет условность понятия "-словарь" и укажет на сайт как на альтернативный вариант понимания названия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это в первую очередь словарь, хотя и расположен он на сайте. Поэтому я считаю правильным вариант **в Викисловаре**.

Пример из Нацкорпуса (газетный корпус):

*В Викисловаре даны такие объяснения: 1) перен. вульг.* [Иван Мальков. Жесточайший ответ Широкова: Бубнову пора место в психбольнице подыскать // Советский спорт, 2013.02.08]